# Can I modify the android project template with some params inputted?

Tags: android, android-studio, templates, gradle

I am trying to modify the Android Studio's NewAndroidProject template, I find it is useless to add parameter in template.xml,also I find that the parameters showed on the panel when I new project are not declared in file template.xml, so is it impossible to add custom parameters on the panel? The same situation is found when new android mudole.

here is the template.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<template
format="5"
revision="5"
name="Android Module"
description="Creates a new Android module.">

<category value="Application" />

<formfactor value="Mobile" />

<thumbs>
    <thumb>template_new_project.png</thumb>
</thumbs>
<parameter
    id="targetApiString"
    name="Target API"
    type="string"
    constraints="apilevel"
    default="19" />

<parameter
    id="buildApi"
    name="Build API level"
    type="string"
    constraints="apilevel"
    default="19" />

//I want to choose the following option on the panel
<parameter
    id="needCustom"
    name="whether need to custom the project"
    type="boolean"
    default="true" />


<globals file="globals.xml.ftl" />
<execute file="recipe.xml.ftl" />
```

what I want is to chose whether to customthe project template on the panel when I create a new Android project,like create a LoginActivity template:
[image]

Comment: Please insert the code / .xml directly into the question instead of a screenshot of the data.

Comment: @Paxz I have updated the question